# React How to searialize an object and pass it to url

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-router

i need to pass an **object** via a **url**(as a parameter) and get it from the other component.
So, i thouht to **stringify** my object and pass it as a parameter, like so:

```
<li key={something}><Link to={{pathname:`/animal/${JSON.stringify(item)}`}}>{item.name}></Link></li>
```

But the url , on the browser now, it turns to show : http://....../animal/[object], that i cant convert it back to json object with JSON.parse().

On the new component i get the `{this.props.params.obj}`, as i have declared it on route: `<Route path='/animabl/:obj'  component={Animal}></Route>` but i cant be transformed back to json object.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good thing to me. Usually you pass the id, and the server will make a request to the database to retrieve the whole object

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by passing my object on the **query** object of the `<Link>` element, like so:

```
<Link to={{pathname:`/animal/${++index}`,query:{'obj':JSON.stringify(item)}}}>{item.name}></Link>
```

**This is the snippet**:

```
var data = this.state.animal.results.map((item,index)=>  { 
            return <li key={index.toString()}>
                <Link to={{pathname:`/animal/${++index}`,query:{'obj':JSON.stringify(item)}}}>{item.name}></Link>
            </li>});
```

**And then,on the new component, i get the `obj` param and convert it to JSON again, like so:**

```
this.props.location.query.obj
```

And inside the **componentDidMount:**

```
componentDidMount:function(){
        /*GET THE OBJECT FROM THE URL PARAM*/
        const tmp =  JSON.parse(this.props.location.query.obj);
        //i manipulate the JSON object....
}
```